# Use timer with random interval

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to run the timer in random interval by using code below. The problem is that when I do this I am posted only 1 random number and I'm not sure how to fetch next random number with my code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Auto_Typer
{
    public partial class AutoTyper : Form
    {
        public AutoTyper()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tmrInterval.Tick += new EventHandler(Interval);

            txtInterval.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextChanged);
            txtMin.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextChanged);
            txtMax.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextChanged);
        }

        private void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (int.Parse(txtInterval.Text) < 1 || int.Parse(txtMin.Text) < 1 || int.Parse(txtMax.Text) < 1)
            {
                txtInterval.Text = "1";
                txtMin.Text = "1";
                txtMax.Text = "1";
            }
            else if (int.Parse(txtInterval.Text) > 100)
            {
                txtInterval.Text = "100";
                txtMin.Text = "100";
                txtMax.Text = "100";
            }
            else if (int.Parse(txtMin.Text) >= int.Parse(txtMax.Text))
            {
                txtMax.Text = (int.Parse(txtMin.Text) + 1).ToString();
            }
        }

        void Interval(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(txtText.Text + ", " + tmrInterval.Interval + "{enter}");
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbType.SelectedTab == tbInterval)
            {
                tmrInterval.Interval = int.Parse(txtInterval.Text) * 1000;
                tmrInterval.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (tbType.SelectedTab == tbRange)
            {
                Random random = new Random();

                tmrInterval.Interval = (random.Next(int.Parse(txtMin.Text), int.Parse(txtMax.Text)) * 1000);
                tmrInterval.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmrInterval.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest moving the "new Random()" call out to your initializer, then simply calling Random.Next() each time you need a new random number.

more info on Random() at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx

Random isn't really random, it's pseudo-random.  This means that given the same starting seed (the argument given to the Random instantiation), subsequent calls to Random.Next() will return the same sequence of values every time.  The good news (thanks, phoog) is that the default constructor (no args) automatically uses a time-based seed.

Comment: Why use the current tick as a seed when you can just call the default constructor, which "initializes a new instance of the Random class, using a time-dependent default seed value"?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the interval in the callback method for a randomly changing interval :

```
private Random random = new Random();

void Interval(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmrInterval.Interval = (random.Next(int.Parse(txtMin.Text), int.Parse(txtMax.Text)) * 1000);
    SendKeys.Send(txtText.Text + ", " + tmrInterval.Interval + "{enter}");
}
```

And also (like above) make the `Random` instance a member field of your class so you don't have to re-new it every time (which might bring problems if called in very fast order).

Comment: @HelpNeeder - Same solution I would have provided

Answer (score 1):

Right now the `Random` instance is created every time the button is clicked because it's a local of the handler.  To persist it between presses you need to make it a field.  -

```
private Random _random = new Random();
```

Now the click handler can get the next random value from the field

```
if (tbType.SelectedTab == tbRange)
{
    tmrInterval.Interval = (_random.Next(int.Parse(txtMin.Text), int.Parse(txtMax.Text)) * 1000);
    tmrInterval.Enabled = true;
}
```